# PHP: merge unknown number of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have one big array structured like this

```
$array = array(

   [0] => array(
      'labels' => array('a', 'b', 'c', [...]),
      'values' => array('val A', 'val B', 'val C', [...])
   ),

   [1] => array(
      'labels' => array('d', 'e', 'f', [...]),
      'values' => array('val D', 'val E', 'val F', [...])
   ),

   [2] => array(
      'labels' => array([...]),
      'values' => array([...])
   ),

   [...],

   [n]

)
```

I want to create a new array for every key, like so:

```
$labels = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', [...])
$values = array('val A', 'val B', 'val C', 'val D', 'val E', 'val F', [...])
```

I would normally use `array_merge`, but I don't know how many arrays I will have.

Is there any way of doing it without looping multiple times ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a loop ?

Comment: `foreach()` should work

Comment: Using individual variables seems like a missed opportunity to sensibly use arrays.  There is no downside to populating an array of rows where you can quickly access data by associative key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some manipulations before building the final array, consider something like this :

```
$labels = array();
$values = array();

$r = array_map(function($subArray) use(&$labels, &$values) {

    // do some stuff here, maybe

    $labels = array_merge($labels, $subArray['labels']);
    $values = array_merge($values, $subArray['values']);

}, $array);
```

Comment: With some tweaks this also works, but I will use Mark's answer. Thank you

Comment: Yep, ok. Beware you need PHP 5.5+ to use Mark's answer.

Comment: Didn't check the version requirement, so your method is the correct one in my case. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$labels = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_column($array, 'labels'));
$values = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_column($array, 'values'));
```

perhaps?

Comment: If you use PHP5.6, you can reduce this code to :
`array_merge(...array_column($array, 'labels'))`
More elegant imho ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I have 5.3 on the client's hosting, so I cannot use your method. It's a shame because I like one liners.